# How do I get the pid of a process run in background?

Tags: shell, background-process

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29681504/452102) approach to run a process in background.

```
"$@" &>/dev/null &disown
```

How do I achieve the following -

1. Get the background `pid`
2. Return it so that it can be consumed in another script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process ID of the most recently started background job is available to the shell as `$!`.

You may, for example output it to a file or to standard output:

```
"$@" &>/dev/null &
disown

printf '%d\n' "$!" >background.pid
```

Another script may then

```
./first-script.sh some command line

thepid=$( <background.pid )
```

Alternatively, if the first script just outputs the process ID to standard output, the second script could

```
thepid=$( ./first-script.sh some command line )
```

Comment: The hardcoding to background.pid is restrictive no? I think we should just print to stdout and whoever wants it can just use it including >background.pid outside? I guess you mentioned that just to show that it is possible to write a file as well.

Comment: @Nishant Yes, I just picked that filename out of thin air. Printing it to stdout or doing whatever else you want to do with it is up to you.

Comment: @Nishant See edited answer.

Comment: Yes. I was in the process of figuring that out, now its a matter of copy-paste :). Thanks!